# A good explanation of naturality (…and not just for natural transformations)

Tags: ct.category-theory

[Leinster - How I Learned to Love the Nerve Construction](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/01/mark_weber_on_nerves_of_catego.html) features some very exceptional mathematicians working on the notion of naturality in Category Theory (and perhaps even mathematics in general).  There is a bit more on the subject at [Leinster - A Perspective on Higher Category Theory](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/03/a_perspective_on_higher_catego.html).

These are blog posts, but you can see they are trying to get at something.  I am trained as a physicist and I really liked Category Theory when I encountered it in my thirties.  The problem that I had was, as I put it, "We are actually, most often, offered a presentation of the theory of Categories in Set".  Furthermore, and perhaps not ironically, you run into very complicated and "clever" definitions like that of Natural Transformation.  That is to say, the standard presentation of category theory is not natural.  Don't take my word for that, but this is where I have ended up in my thinking on this.

What I am wondering is whether or not someone can give a good explanation about the concept of naturality in Category Theory, and perhaps Mathematics.  Can we apply this concept to the presentation of the theory of Categories itself?  Also, if one has a link to a refereed publication on the subject, please do share.

Comment: This looks like a request for more blog posts, which are great things indeed, but doesn't seem like the right kind of question for MO.

Comment: Why do you think the usual presentation of categories is not natural? It developed out of a large number of examples that had been studied earlier (categories of groups, vector spaces, commutative tings, topological spaces, and so on). They shared many similar structural concepts relating mappings and objects. Had you seen many of these examples before you encountered category theory?

Comment: KConrad's comments are entirely valid and @TomLeinster writes some great blog posts. However, category theory now has so many different applications and so many different accounts that newcomers should not form their opinions on just one of them.

Comment: @KConrad Compare the standard definition of a natural transformation to the following: "A natural transformation takes a functor and produces another functor".  This is glib, I know, but think of all the work that is done to reason about categories when you are using Set.  You can really calculate things, but those are really just Set like things.  You are calculating set-like things that are models of categories.  When the calculations become onerous, one must be tempted to look around.